# Sonos SMAPI: how to publish track/artist information correctly as a radio-type music service?

Tags: sonos

I'm trying to get our Music Service's SMAPI validated with Sonos. Automated tests passed. I'm now getting what looks like the results of manual QA tests from the Sonos support.

In the "Now Playing/Queue" category, a test named **"Is track/artist information displayed under On Now correctly?"** is marked as failed with the notice **"Track and Artist are displayed under "Information", while the "On Now" section is blank."**. I'm providing continuous radio-type Streams, not single tracks.

I can't correlate the mentioned "Information" and "On Now" sections (which probably refer to their controller App's GUI) with the API I'm implementing. In fact, we don't provide any artist/track information via the SMAPI as this information is extracted from the http stream's metadata by the controller.

So I wonder why they complain about where this information is being displayed as I don't seem to have any influence over it.

Could anybody please point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to populate these fields on the now playing screen by using the description and currentShow metadata elements in the streamMetadata response to getMediaMetadata.  This should be enough to pass validation.

If metadata for the track itself is embedded in the stream Sonos should be able to parse it out.

Comment: So am I right assuming that if our stream contains embedded artist/title information, I should not be required to provide it via the smapi at all?